# How to know very first value inserted in table in mysql

Tags: mysql

Ok, i have a table having multiple values. Now i want to know which tuple is the oldest one (the very first one among all inserted in the table). Is there any way to know it?

Comment: You created the db schema, why don't you make it easy for yourself and add extra information such as.. when the particular record was created? Then you can easily determine which record is "first" using date/auto_increment to find that information.

Comment: no, actually i got the db from some external sources. i have the table and i just want to know which entry was the first one.

Comment: It would be easier to provide the answer had we seen the schema in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to achieve this, if you have a `datetime` or `timestamp` column in your table which holds the date of insertion of records. Then you can, refer that date column and get the oldest record.

Other way, may not be accurate; is to order by a field with limit; like

```
SELECT   *
FROM     your_table
WHERE    value='value1'
ORDER BY field1 
LIMIT    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options here depending on your table structure. Since that is missing it is hard to help you out. My guess would be sort on a timestamp or id and get the oldest one.